# Wubi - Permission denied "errno" 13

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permission denied: 'F:\\wubildr' when install using Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87014/permission-denied-f-wubildr-when-install-using-wubi)

After Wubi finishes, I get an error message saying "permission denied errno 13

This is the end of the  log file:

```
**01-26 09:51 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:\\wubildr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 483, in diskimage_bootloader
  File "\lib\shutil.py", line 39, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:\\wubildr'
01-26 09:51 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
01-26 09:51 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
01-26 09:51 ERROR  root: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:\\wubildr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 483, in diskimage_bootloader
  File "\lib\shutil.py", line 39, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:\\wubildr'**
```

I have nothing in drive F:, it's empty.

Ubuntu will run, but freezes after a few minutes.

Any ideas how I can fix this problem?  Have I missed a step?

Computer is an HP pavilion HPE, I'm logged on as administrator.

Comment: Hello jamsie, please have a look at a similar question here [Permission denied: 'F:\\wubildr' when install using Wubi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87014/permission-denied-f-wubildr-when-install-using-wubi). The user marked it as solved, maybe that will also be a solution for you.